# How does Entity Framework know whether the update/insert/delete affected any rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I've mapped an Insert/Update/Delete functions to an Entity `Employee`. I've then modified an entity with `EmployeeID=100` and called `SaveChanges`, and in turn EF called Update Store Procedure ( **USP** ) for that entity

a)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployee
...   
AS

UPDATE Employee
SET ...
WHERE EmployeeID=1000 // EF throws an exception, since there aren't any rows with
                      // EmployeeID=1000 and thus no rows were affected 
SELECT ...
```

At first I thought that only information that DB will return back to the caller ( caller being EF ) is the number of rows affected by the last statement in USP. Thus even if **USP** didn't manage to update any rows, EF would still think that update was successfull, since DB would report that one row was affected (due to `SELECT` statement). But it appears that information returned to the caller also specifies whether rows were affected by the `SELECT` statement or by the `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statement?! Correct?

b)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployee
...
AS

INSERT INTO Employee
...
```

I assume that information returned back to the caller doesn't specify whether rows were affected by `INSERT` or by `UPDATE` or by `DELETE` statement? Is that the reason why EF  considers an update successful even if **USP** inserted a row instead of updating a row ( with `EmployeeID=100` )?

c) But why does EF consider an update successful even when **USP** doesn't execute any `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements? As noted in my above questions, doesn't information returned back to the caller specify whether any rows were affected by `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`? If yes, then EF should throw an exception when calling the following **USP**, but it doesn't. Why?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployee
...
AS

/*no statements*/
```

Thank you